# Setting text to multiple TextFields with Asynctasks crashes app

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

What I want to achieve is the following:
In my view, I have 4 TextViews that should show the amount of items in the connected databases. This is done using a simple php script.

The problem I have is that I get all the correct values from the database, but when I try to set those values to my TextViews, the app crashes.

I have tried to look if using to many Asynctasks could be a problem, but when I decide to comment out the only line inside the **SetTextForTextView()** function, it all works like a charm and all the expected values are printed to my log. So with that being said, I dont think using multiple Asynctasks at the same time is the problem here, but I have really no idea what is.

Something that might be worth mentioning is when I comment out the following bit like this, the app doesn't crash...

```
        shoesAmount = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.menuTvShoesAmount);
        DatabaseTask taskA = new DatabaseTask(shoesAmount);
        taskA.execute("getAmount", "shoes");

//        tshirtsAmounts = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.menuTvTshirtsAmount);
//        DatabaseTask taskB = new DatabaseTask(tshirtsAmounts);
//        taskB.execute("getAmount", "tshirts");
//
//        jeansAmount = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.menuTvJeansAmount);
//        DatabaseTask taskC = new DatabaseTask(jeansAmount);
//        taskC.execute("getAmount", "jeans");
//
//        blousesAmount = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.menuTvBlousesAmount);
//        DatabaseTask taskD = new DatabaseTask(blousesAmount);
//        taskD.execute("getAmount", "blouses");
```

But then again with any other combination for example like this one, and the app crashes again...

```
//        shoesAmount = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.menuTvShoesAmount);
//        DatabaseTask taskA = new DatabaseTask(shoesAmount);
//        taskA.execute("getAmount", "shoes");
//
        tshirtsAmounts = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.menuTvTshirtsAmount);
        DatabaseTask taskB = new DatabaseTask(tshirtsAmounts);
        taskB.execute("getAmount", "tshirts");
//
//        jeansAmount = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.menuTvJeansAmount);
//        DatabaseTask taskC = new DatabaseTask(jeansAmount);
//        taskC.execute("getAmount", "jeans");
//
//        blousesAmount = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.menuTvBlousesAmount);
//        DatabaseTask taskD = new DatabaseTask(blousesAmount);
//        taskD.execute("getAmount", "blouses");
```

Does anyone can point me out into the direction where I might be going wrong?

Thanks!
(here is the full code)

```
package ishopper.theindiestudio.com.appname;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.HorizontalScrollView;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Menu extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ImageButton btnHelp, btnAccount, newest1, newest2, newest3;
    private TextView shoesAmount, tshirtsAmounts, jeansAmount, blousesAmount;
    private Button browseShoes, browseTshirts, browseJeans, browseBlouses;

    private Context context;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu);

        context = this;

        btnHelp = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.menuBtnHelp);
        btnAccount = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.menuBtnAccount);

        btnAccount.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                onAccountOptions();
            }
        });
        btnHelp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                onHelp();
            }
        });

        newest1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.menuIbNewest1);
        newest2 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.menuIbNewest2);
        newest3 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.menuIbNewest3);
        //set newest items

        shoesAmount = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.menuTvShoesAmount);
        DatabaseTask taskA = new DatabaseTask(shoesAmount);
        taskA.execute("getAmount", "shoes");

        tshirtsAmounts = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.menuTvTshirtsAmount);
        DatabaseTask taskB = new DatabaseTask(tshirtsAmounts);
        taskB.execute("getAmount", "tshirts");

        jeansAmount = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.menuTvJeansAmount);
        DatabaseTask taskC = new DatabaseTask(jeansAmount);
        taskC.execute("getAmount", "jeans");

        blousesAmount = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.menuTvBlousesAmount);
        DatabaseTask taskD = new DatabaseTask(blousesAmount);
        taskD.execute("getAmount", "blouses");

    }

    public void SetTextForTextView(TextView textview, String result){
        textview.setText(result);
    }

    public void onAccountOptions () {
        Intent i = new Intent(this, AccountDetailsActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }

    public void onHelp () {

    }

    public void onBackPressed() {
        //disabled back button
    }

    private class DatabaseTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        private String taskType;
        private String productType;
        private TextView textView;
        private ImageButton imageButton;

        DatabaseTask (TextView mTextView){textView = mTextView;}

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            String task = params[0];
            if (task.equals("getAmount")) {
                Log.e("doInBg", "getAmount");

                String login_url = "http://url.eu/directory/script.php";
                String tProductType = params[1];
                try {
                    URL url = new URL(login_url);
                    HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                    httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                    httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
                    OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
                    BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));
                    String postData = URLEncoder.encode("producttable", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(tProductType, "UTF-8");
                    bufferedWriter.write(postData);
                    bufferedWriter.flush();
                    bufferedWriter.close();
                    outputStream.close();
                    InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "iso-8859-1"));
                    String result = "";
                    String line = "";
                    while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                        result += line;
                        Log.e("doInBgResult", result.toString());
                    }
                    bufferedReader.close();
                    inputStream.close();
                    httpURLConnection.disconnect();

                    Menu activity = (Menu) context;
                    activity.SetTextForTextView(textView, result.toString());


                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `AsyncTask`'s `doInBackground()` runs in another thread and you can't change the UI from another thread, Only the main one. I suggest you do the same job in `onPostExecute()` after you finish your long job. Return the `String result` you want to use to the main thread

```
bufferedReader.close();
inputStream.close();
httpURLConnection.disconnect();

// no need for that
//Menu activity = (Menu) context;
//activity.SetTextForTextView(textView, result.toString());

reutrn result;
```

then update the text

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    if(result != null){
        SetTextForTextView(textView, result);
    }
}
```

I suggest reading more about it from [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) and [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html)

Comment: Thanks!
I read about the UI thread thing, that's why I make the doInBackground call the function on my UI thread. However, what is the difference between by using the OnPostExecute, or doing it the way I did it, after the connection was closed. Because at that point it sounds to me like everything is done, and ready to be applied to the TextField? I thought this would be more directer instead of calling in an extra function just to do that...

P.s. i'm a autodidact programmer with a background in game development, that's why I might be missing some crucial info when I moved to app development.

Comment: You're welcome. Your `AsyncTask` class in an inner or "nested" class so it can access methods and global variables from the outer or "parent" class. `SetTextForTextView()` is just in the outer class not in another thread, It can be accessed from both main UI thread and new threads, it just depends on the caller thread. Here in your case in `doInBackground()` you're in "new thread" and called the other method but "still in new thread" so you can't update the UI. but when `doInBackground()` finishes, it returns to the main thread "onPostExecute()" where you can update the UI freely.

Comment: Ahh that makes sense!
Many thanks again. How can I give these points to comments btw?